# URL redirection for rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I installed `devise` on my rails projects, and after navigating from this URL -

`http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`

it is redirecting to this URL - `http://localhost:3000/`

really dont know what exactly the problem is, checked `routes.rb` file as well.

My project location - https://github.com/swapnesh/prjmgttool

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I checked out your project, initialized and migrated the database and went to /users/sign_in - getting the input form.

The only weird thing I can see is that your routes.rb doesn't contain a default route, so going to / leads to an error: No route matches [GET] "/"

Have you restarted your rails server after adding devise?

Comment: @KarstenS. thx at very first impression it works for me too..but when i Signed up...and refer to the same URl it is redirecting me ..plz sign_up then i believe you will able to reproduce the problem

Comment: @KarstenS. I followed this link, and things are on my local system  http://blog.andolasoft.com/2012/11/how-to-install-devise-in-rails-3-x.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, that's pretty easy then, because you're already signed in.
Devise will redirect you to the start page after a successful login AND if you're already logged in and try to call the sign_in page.
You need to log out first (or delete the cookie manually) to see the login form again.

Comment: Perfect..just a question..where do i find session/cookies for rail project ? as i checked this in chrome and its working fine

Comment: The cookie is stored in your browser. If you're developing using your rails server, you'll find them under localhost.
However, you should avoid playing around with the cookie as soon as possible and add a sign-out link to your project to log off.
Then start developing your default view to actually get something to see.

Comment: I am new to rails, so thought to start by building a user registration form and came across this "devise" and trying to implement the same...just for my knowledge..is it a right path im taking to learn rails as I have to cover rails within a month constraint...just share if yo have any idea/links to follow as i am already familiar with PHP :)

Comment: You might try out http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book which helped me. There is plenty of other stuff around like http://railscasts.com and more.

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup a root url to some controller action you would like to use after the user has logged in.

```
# in routes.rb
root to: 'example_controller#show'
```